# Lazy connect doesn't work

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I'm using Node Wrangler's Lazy Connect. But it simply doesn't work at all. For example when I try to connect these two nodes:

[image]

And nothing happens. What's going on?

Comment: are u windows or macos user? what keys are you pressing/holding? and...it does work. I had similar problems because i made something wrong....

Comment: Weirdly, it works again after I remove Lazy Connect's keymapping and reset it.